# Jquery Autocomplete using with weather underground api

Tags: jquery-ui, jsonp, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use autocomplete with weather underground API. but its not giving any popups on  HTML field but it shows output in console. please check below code and advice.

```
      $(document).ready(function($){
 $('#input').autocomplete({
   source:function (request, response) {
  $("#input").keyup(function(me){
   var  city=$(this).val();


   $.ajax({

url:"http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query="+city+"&c=US&cb=call=?",
dataType: "jsonp",
crossDomain: true,
success: function (parsed_json) {
//console.log(JSON.stringify( parsed_json));
  response( $.each(parsed_json.RESULTS,
  function(i,item){

    return JSON.stringify( parsed_json.RESULTS[i].name);

         }));

},

 error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status);
alert(thrownError);
   }

  });


    });
   }
 });

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

After struggle three days i made it works.below is working code and i made  [js Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/preetparm/f9tfs7xq/1/) .Hope it  help others. 
Please suggest me if any other better way in your mind 
Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
 var i;
 var out;
var arr=[];

$('#autocomplete').keyup(function(){
var value=$(this).val();           

$.ajax({
url:"http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?&c=IN&cb=call=?",
dataType: "jsonp",
data:{
"query":value
},
crossDomain: true,
success: function (parsed_json) {
var c =$.each(parsed_json.RESULTS,function(i,item){
out=(parsed_json.RESULTS[i].name);
 arr.push(out);

 });
 $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
 source:arr

});

},
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status);
alert(thrownError);
    }

  }); 
      });


});
html:
<div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="autocomplete">Select a city: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">
      </div>
```